# Copiar archivos recientes mediante .bat

Tags: batch, .bat

Buen dia

Hoy vengo solicitando de su ayuda para ver en que falle con este .bat

Lo que hace es copiar todos los archivos de la fecha establecida por el parametro date.

Si realiza la funcion me copea solo los archivos de esa fecha pero como se genera un archivo nuevo cada hora en la carpeta ocupo que el .bat se ejecute cada hora y lo hace mediante una tarea de windows la cual falla debido a que el .bat me pide sobreescribir los archivos

El punto aqui es busco cualquiera de las siguientes 2 soluciones:

1.Poder realizar la copia y que en automatico sobreescriba los archivos

ó

2.Que solo me realiza la copia del archivo mas reciente ó archivos mas recientes

Les dejo el codigo que uso

```
@echo off

set source=\\ctjstore01\jmc_rmms
set destination=C:\Apache24\htdocs\ScanningHour\Reports

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('"echo %date%"') do ( set "CURDATE=%%a" )

xcopy /d:%curdate% %source%\*.* C:\Apache24\htdocs\ScanningHour\Reports
```

De antemano gracias

Comment: podrias explicar como tienes guardados los archivos porque a si es muy dificil de poder replicar tu carpeta donde tienes el codigo guardado

Comment: Los archivos estan en una carpeta compartida y cada hora se sube un archivo nuevo con registros de esa hora el .bat funciona correctamente el problema es que la tarea se detiene debido a que copea todos los que esten de esa fecha a la hora que se ejecuta entonces lo unico que quiero es evitar que haga copias de los archivos ya existentes y solo tome en cuenta los nuevos o mas recientes

Comment: una forma seria que los nombres de los archivos sea un contador por ejemplo el pimer archivo seria 1 el segundo seria 2 el tercero seria 3 y asi y que tu programa tuviese una variable con valor inicial 1 y que se incremente cada vez que se hace una copia